# How to detect special url android programmatically

Tags: input, instagram, limit

i've bought an instagram downloader source code and it can download photos and videos and profile pictures from Instagram. It has an edittext to get the address of pictures and videos and profile pictures. i wanna limit getting profile pictures addresses i've no idea how to do that because i'm new to Android, please help me, thank you so much